# No sé como hacer los drops en mi trabajo

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Ahora mismo estoy haciendo un trabajo que me hace falta para un cliente. He creado las tablas y me compilan bien pero me dan muchos errores de que los nombres están en uso. Creo que es porque no tengo puestos los drops. El problema que tengo es que no sé en que orden hacerlos. Sé que cuando una tabla está referenciada por una foreign key no se puede hacer drop pero cuando deja de estar sí. Tuve eso en cuenta a la hora de poner código y no me sale. Dejo el código adjunto. Muchas gracias.

```
CREATE TABLE LOCALIZACION_CILINDROS (
 ZONA_ALMACEN_C VARCHAR2(100) PRIMARY KEY,
 STOCK_MINIMO_TIPO_C NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
 STOCK_TIPO_C NUMBER(4) NOT NULL
 );


CREATE TABLE SEAL_KITS (
  TIPO_SEAL_KIT NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  ZONA_DEL_ALMACEN_SK VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(ZONA_DEL_ALMACEN_SK) REFERENCES LOCALIZACION_SEAL_KITS
);


CREATE TABLE LOCALIZACION_SEAL_KITS(
ZONA_DEL_ALMACEN_SK VARCHAR2(100) PRIMARY KEY,
STOCK_MINIMO_TIPO_SK NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
STOCK_TIPO_SK NUMBER(4) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE CILINDROS (
Nº_TIPO_CILINDRO VARCHAR2(12) PRIMARY KEY,
Nº_VECES_EN_TALLER NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
ESTADO VARCHAR2(30) CHECK ( ESTADO = 'NUEVO' || 'TALLER' || 'FUERA'),
Nº_HORAS_TRABAJADAS NUMBER(5) ,
ALBARAN NUMBER(7) ,
TIPO_SEAL_KIT NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
TIPO_MAQUINA VARCHAR2(100) CHECK(TIPO_MAQUINA = 'JUMBO' || 'SIMBA' || 'MARTILLO' || 'BOLTEC' || 'CABLETEC' || 'SIMBA/JUMBO/MARTILLO' || 'CAMISA BOMBA'),
ZONA_ALMACEN_C VARCHAR2(100),
ORDEN_TRABAJO NUMBER(7),
FOREIGN KEY(TIPO_SEAL_KIT) REFERENCES SEAL_KITS,
FOREIGN KEY(TIPO_MAQUINA) REFERENCES MAQUINAS,
FOREIGN KEY(ZONA_ALMACEN_C) REFERENCES LOCALIZACION_CILINDROS,
FOREIGN KEY(ORDEN_TRABAJO) REFERENCES INFORMES_DE_BAJAS_DE_CILINDROS
);


CREATE TABLE MAQUINAS (
TIPO_MAQUINA VARCHAR2(100) PRIMARY KEY,
Nº_MAQUINA NUMBER(20) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE INFORMES_DE_BAJAS_DE_CILINDROS (
ORDEN_TRABAJO NUMBER(7) PRIMARY KEY,
RAZON VARCHAR2(200),
IMAGEN VARCHAR2(200)
);


CREATE TABLE INF_REPARACION (
ORDEN_TRABAJO NUMBER(7) PRIMARY KEY,
RAZON VARCHAR2(200)
);
```

Comment: [Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Con este script que muestras, ¿te arroja algún error?, ¿ya ha consultado la [documentación sobre cómo eliminar tablas](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-ED12D782-1807-4B92-B535-431EA8F4B12E.htm#ADMQS0827)?. Lo que entiendo de su pregunta es que quiere borrar y crear nuevamente las tablas *(no se si eso es lo que quiere)*, pero, le recomiendo revisar bien lo que quiere hacer y explíquelo claramente en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes borrar primero las tablas hijas (las que definen la relación a la otra tabla) antes que las padres (las que contienen los datos referenciados), pero requiere que conozcas muy bien el esquema y las relaciones.

Si quieres simplificar el trabajo y borrar una tabla eliminando sus restricciones de claves foráneas en otras tablas debes hacer uso de [`CASCADE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables010.htm#ADMIN01505):

```
DROP TABLE LOCALIZACION_CILINDROS CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
```

En la documentación se puede leer:

> If the table to be dropped contains any primary or unique keys referenced by foreign keys of other tables and you intend to drop the `FOREIGN KEY` constraints of the child tables, then include the `CASCADE` clause in the `DROP TABLE` statement, as shown below.

En castellano:

> Si la tabla que va a ser borrada contiene una clave primaria o clave única que está siendo referenciada por otras tablas y tu intención es borrar las restricciones `FOREIGN KEY` de esas tablas hijas, entonces incluye la cláusula `CASCADE` en la consulta `DROP TABLE`, como se muestra a continuación.

De esa manera da igual el orden en el que borres las tablas siempre que vuelvas a crearlas en el orden correcto.

NOTA: Recuerda que si no has borrado una tabla que referenciaba a una de las tablas que has borrado usando `CASCADE` deberás volver a crear el `FOREIGN KEY` con un `ALTER TABLE`.

Si quieres hacer este mismo borrado usando las opciones de SQL Developer entonces debes seguir las instrucciones que te ha dado [@Mauricio Arias Olave](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/78/mauricio-arias-olave) de [este enlace](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-ED12D782-1807-4B92-B535-431EA8F4B12E.htm#ADMQS0827).

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya funciona!!!

Comment: De nada, un placer. Si consideras que es la respuesta correcta recuerda marcarla como tal. Gracias.